# Purpose of an EpiServer MenuList's page link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, episerver-6

Cannot seem to grasp the concept of PageLink attributes for EpiServer listing controls. I need to understand this: ["PageLink: Provides a page reference to a page; the children of that page will become the collection used."](http://world.episerver.com/Get-Started/EPiServer-CMS/Introduction-to-EPiServer-CMS/EPiServer-List-and-Menu-Controls-/) Supposing I'd like to use a MenuList - what sort of 'children' will be/can be used as a datasource to a menu control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [EPiServer documentation](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/html/P_EPiServer_Core_PageData_PageLink.htm)

> As PageLink is guaranteed to be unique among all pages in a certain
>   EPiServer instances, it is used in the following example to create
>   unique IDs and names for HTML check boxes. The code is used to present
>   the visitor with a selection of pages and allows them to select one or
>   more for further processing.

My understanding is that if you set a `PageLink` in your listing control, it will have access to the child pages based on that page.